# Android Studio - ¿Como setear la fecha actual, la de los 6 días pasados y los 6 días siguientes?

Tags: android, android-studio, date, viewpager

**Descripción:**

Tengo una actividad tabbeada (**Tabed Activity**) la cual contiene un **Text View** del siguiente estilo: (Mar. 03, 2020). También hay un **View pager** que intercambia entre siete distintos **Fragments** (fragment Lunes, hasta fragment domingo). La idea es que dependiendo del día en el que estemos, este text view contenga la fecha según el fragment en el que estamos situados.

**Ejemplo:**

Hoy es Martes 3 de Marzo del 2.020 por lo que al estar situados en **Fragment Martes**, este contendrá la fecha actual. Lo interesante es que si vamos hacia **Fragment Miércoles**, este txt deberá mostrar "Marzo 04, 2020" (un día después). Pero si volvemos hacia atrás (**Fragment Lunes**) el text view deberá mostrar  la fecha del próximo Lunes (Marzo 9, 2020).

**A tener en cuenta:**

No quiero que nunca se muestre una fecha pasada. Siempre la actual y las que continúan.

**¿Como puedo hacer esto?**

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

txtFecha.setText(ano+"-"+(mes)+"-"+(dia));
                        txtFechaVen.setText(String.format("%02d-%02d-%02d",ano, (mes+1),dia)
```

De esta manera puedes obtener la fecha y setearla en el formato que desees. Para resolver el problema de mostrar los días posteriores, puedes utilizar `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` y sumarle días dependiendo del fragment en donde se encuentre.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: No me es de ayuda. El problema que intento resolver es justamente el que no me pudiste contestar. Igualmente te agradezco por la respuesta